# MVC, problemas al pasar datos de una View a un Controller

Tags: java, mvc, java-swing

Tengo una clase `PaneClient`, la cual usa `CardLayout` y "encima" de esta view están otras 2 views: `paneAttributeSet` y `paneRegisterClient` .

El problema está cuando trato de llamar el método `getFieldData()` desde el controlador `PaneRegisterClientController` de la view `paneRegisterClient` haciendo click en el botón Register de dicha view, el método debe restituir un objeto de tipo `Client` inicializado con el input del usuario que seria el ID y nombre del client , pero los valores asignados al objeto `Client` terminan siendo nulos, es como si el método no lograra asignar los valores insertados en los textfields.

Clase `PaneClient`:

```
public class PaneClient{

..........botones para CRUD.............
    private JPanel viewClientPane;

    private ClientView clientView = new ClientView();


private AttributesView theAttribView = new AttributesView();

    private ClientAttributeSetManagement paneAttributeSet = new ClientAttributeSetManagement();
    public PaneRegisterClient paneRegisterClient = new PaneRegisterClient();

    public PaneClient() {

        setLayout(new CardLayout());
        initComponents();

    }

    protected void initComponents() {

    MigLayout layout = new MigLayout("wrap 2", "[grow] [] ", "[] [] []");
    viewClientPane = new JPanel(layout);

    // put all the panels together
    viewClientPane.add(clientView, "flowx,alignx left,growy");
    viewClientPane.add(getCrudButtonsPanel(), "cell 0 0");
    viewClientPane.add(theAttribView, "cell 0 1");
    viewClientPane.add(getNavButtonsPanel(), "south");

// añade las views

        add(viewClientPane, "viewClientPane");
        add(paneAttributeSet, "pane Aset");
        add(paneRegisterClient, "pane Register client");

    }
public PaneRegisterClient getPaneRegisterClient() {
    return paneRegisterClient;
}
}
```

La clase `PaneRegisterClient`:

```
private JButton registerButton = new JButton("Register");
private JButton backButton = new JButton("Back");
private JButton finishButton = new JButton("Finish");

public JTextField txtClientID = new JTextField(5);
public JTextField txtName = new JTextField(15);

private JPanel registerClientView;

public PaneRegisterClient() {
    setLayout(new CardLayout());
    initComponents();
}

private void initComponents() {

    attributeView = new AttributesView();

    MigLayout layout = new MigLayout("wrap 2", "[grow] [] ", "[] [] []");
    viewClientPane = new JPanel(layout);

    // put all the panels together
    viewClientPane.add(getRegisterUserView(), "flowx,alignx left,growy");
    viewClientPane.add(attributeView, "flowx,cell 0 1");
    viewClientPane.add(registerButton, "cell 0 1");
    viewClientPane.add(getNavButtonsPanel(), "south");

    add(viewClientPane, "viewUserPane");

}

private JPanel getRegisterUserView() {
    registerClientView = getPanel("Client data");
    registerClientView.setLayout(new MigLayout("wrap 2", "[] 16 []"));

    registerClientView.add(new JLabel("Client ID:"), "right");
    registerClientView.add(txtClientID);

    registerClientView.add(new JLabel("Name:"), "right");
    registerClientView.add(txtName);

    return registerClientView;
}
public boolean isEmptyFieldData() {
    return (txtClientID.getText().trim().isEmpty() && txtName.getText().trim().isEmpty());
}

// el metodo llamado que no funziona
    public Client getFieldData() {
        Client client = new Client();

    client.setClientID(txtClientID.getText());
    client.setClientName(txtName.getText());

    System.out.println("method getfieldata: " + client.getClientID() + client.getClientName());

    return client;
}
public void addNavListener(ActionListener navListener) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    backButton.addActionListener(navListener);
    finishButton.addActionListener(navListener);
}

public void addRegListener(ActionListener regListener) {
    registerButton.addActionListener(regListener);
}
```

Controller `PaneRegisterClientController`:

```
public class PaneRegisterClientController {
private PaneClient paneClient;
private PaneRegisterClient paneRegisterClient;

private ClientBean clientBean = new ClientBean();

public PaneRegisterClientController(PaneClient pClient) {

    this.paneClient = pClient;
    this.paneRegisterClient = pClient.getPaneRegisterClient();

    initComponents();

    paneRegisterClient.addNavListener(new NavListener());
    paneRegisterClient.addRegListener(new RegListener());
}

private void initComponents() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}

class RegListener implements ActionListener {

    Client client = paneRegisterClient.getFieldData();

    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {

        switch (e.getActionCommand()) {

        case "Register":

            if (paneRegisterClient.isEmptyFieldData()) {
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Some fields are empty");
                return;
            }

            if (clientBean.create(client) != null) {

                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "New user registered successfully.");

                client.setClientID("");
                client.setClientName("");
                paneRegisterClient.setFieldData(client);
            }
            break;

        }
    }
```

Tengo la sospecha que el error esta en la forma en como asigno la view PaneRegisterClient en el costructor del controllador:

```
private PaneClient paneClient;
private PaneRegisterClient paneRegisterClient;

public PaneRegisterClientController(PaneClient pClient) {

    this.paneClient = pClient;
    this.paneRegisterClient = pClient.getPaneRegisterClient();
.......
```

En fin, la pregunta es: cuál sería una forma correcta de pasar datos hacia el controlador usando el `CardLayout` y evitarme dicho problema?

[Aquí pueden encontrar mi proyecto entero](https://github.com/StratosNB/UsersManagement_AdminUI)

Comment: Para recoger los valores de los text de un java-swing, cuando agregas un elemento, verás abajo de tu código, dicho elemento, debes asignar ese elemento auto-generado por java a una declaración tuya de ese componente, para que estén referenciados.,

Comment: A que te refieres con "veras abajo de tu codigo dicho elemento¨"?

Comment: Cuando generas elemento con javaSwing, como un input, java genera el elemento en código de programación (no solo visual), y donde escribes el código, tienes que coger la variable de eso que está generando, para poder obtener la referencia a ese elemento que has creado arrastrándolo a la pantalla, viene en color gris, al final de la página.

Comment: Sigo sin entender, por que lo siguiente no seria suficiente?: client.setClientID(txtClientID.getText());
client.setClientName(txtName.getText());